# Rendering clipped/mask SVG files in Scribus/InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, clipping-mask, scribus

Scribus can't do this, so I'm wondering first of all if InDesign can. If not, are there any other ways to modify the shape of an object which *would* render it in one or both of these programs?

Answer (score 0):

Alright mates figured it out, I can simply convert the object to a PNG file and edit it in GIMP/Photoshop then import it back into Inkscape, no worries.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. Scribus does not support all the SVG features. In most cases, the missing features relate to the fact that they do not directly translate into PDFs.